# How to frame a wall around existing exterior door

Tags: doors, basement, framing, foundation

Framing a basement.  I have a an exterior door that is set in the poured foundation.  I'm building my wall that runs parallel to foundation that has the existing door and is ~2-4" from the foundation.  How do I frame this opening?  Of particular concern, if I from perpendicular from the wall to the in-swing door, it would seem that I wouldn't be able to open the door more than 85-90 degrees.

Edit: added pictures for more clarity
[image]

[image]

Edit 2: Added diagram of proposed layout (minus solution)

[image]

Edit 3. Added new diagram
[image]

Edit 4. 4th times a charm
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the picture & diagram updates, your initial question was a little unclear to me. You'll have to move the door in order for it to open more than 90-degrees & to flat upon the wall.

Move the door, its jamb & threshold inside to be flush with the new stud wall's drywall finished surface elevation for a full door swing. Then, extend the door jamb (sides & top) out to the exterior wall & re-apply the exterior trim. This provides a good exterior recess & overhang to protect the door & threshold from weather & spiders will love it.

Additionally, since your door will now be mounted to your interior stud wall instead of the very & completely solid foundation wall. You'll want to solidify the stud wall & attach it to the door's existing framing with a toe-nailed or toe-screwed 2x4 bridging connector. This will also assist greatly with the jamb extensions & their seamless alignment.

Comment: I think the problem is the door itself will pinch on what will be an overly thick frame. Where as, currently it can probably open almost to a 180. I like the pocket idea, but the entire frame on the hinge side needs to be a 45 e.g., to allow the door to swing further.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm not sure I'm getting his meaning. Are we talking about where the handle hits the stud wall or are we talking about the door hitting the stud wall that sticking out further than the hinges. Option 1 handles the handle. And, option 2 handles both scenario's.

Comment: I added some (crappy) pictures to help visualize what I mean.  The base plate would be roughly where it is in the picture and the studs would be facing that way.  So from what I was expecting was to run a board flush with the end of the last stud to the door, kind of like you'd do with a window.  But then that'd prevent the door from opening more than 90 degrees

Comment: Ah thank you, that's much better. I thought it was a corner situation, not a middle spot. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So, I'm trying to parse your answer, but I think I'm a little dense.  What do you mean by on-flat - Do you mean put the 3.5" width parallel with the face of the door or perpendicular to the face of the door? Let me also clarify that I'd like my base plate to *start* 3" from the foundation wall and the door jam sticks out 1".

Comment: I added a Sketchup of what the proposed layout is.   Can you use that to show what you mean?

Comment: While your pictures showed what's in the diagram, I didn't or don't understand why the wall is out so much...accept of course being for additional insulation. But, ignore the framing options & I'll remove them from my answer, they only applied for the wall being installed against the existing insulation. You'll have no other choice but to move the door, if you want it to open more than 90-degrees.

Comment: What about have the wall be flush just for a foot or 2 by the door, then bump out for the 2x4 the rest of the wall. You'd lose a little insulation but not have to move the door, I believe. (would just be adding drywall next to the door)

Comment: Yeah, that's what my initial answer had. Doing the walls with studs on-flat for the walls entirely as 1 option & another option was to do on-flats just around the door. But, with a 2x8 depth the walls would look weird & he still wouldn't get a flat opened door. Though, I have seen the swing side's wall done on-flat for almost the full width of the door, so the door edge seals against the bump-out corner & the handle doesn't hit anything, but that only looks good when the door's fully open.

Comment: So I REALLY don't want to move the door.  I don't need the door to open 180, but I'd like it to open more than 90 if possible. When you say the studs "on-flat", do you mean the 3.5" side running parallel to the exterior wall or perpendicular to the wall?

Comment: So there's the rub. Doors aren't tough, watch a few YouTube vids. But yep, it can stay. And yep again, On-Flat is the 3.5" being parallel to the wall, you'd want to do no stand-off from the wall treating the framing like door trim. If you want to get fancy, make it decorative instead of an oddity, you can offset (3" so you can add molding later, if desired) another layer of On-Flats upon the 1st. Or, use thinner wood On-Flat so the steps (when drywalled) are all the same depth. Take it as far as you want to get closer to 180-degrees, but do both sides of the door.

Comment: So I added a picture of how I am interpreting your comment.  I put the 2x4's on-flat next to jam.  But how do I put the casing on?  Normally the drywall is flush with the jam, and the casing goes onto the jam with a 3/8" or so reveal.  There's no way to do that unless I used 1/2" wide wood instead of 1 1/2" 2x's

Comment: Yep, whatever thickness it takes. I didn't know if you would or wouldn't be installing casing. Since, you have a double stud holding the door you can pull the On-Flat(s) back & do a thin Quarter-round (type of cove molding) transition to your casing. Or, skip the first On-Flat & use a Brick Mold as your casing, they're thicker not wider. You can butt the 2x4's like in your diagram or you can offset stack them.

Comment: So here's my latest hairbrain idea (see new edit).  Can I use 1/2 plywood as a spacer [or any particular type of 1/2" wood] to act as a backer to make the 1/2" drywall flush with the jam?  I'd use a smaller casing then I was originally thinking, and then I'd bring the studs as close to the wall as possible (in the diagram there's a 1/2" gap).   The door would only be able to open 90 degrees, but we were thinking of maybe adding a closet down the road which might actually go right there, so it'd be a moot point anyway.

Comment: Why drywall at all there & why a 1/2" gap that'll be a pain in the butt to paint? Just go with 1x4 (still 3.5" width I'm assuming) & drywall just on the adjacent face to then slap your casing right against it. Even with a future closet that should be plenty for the door handle & a full 90-degree door swing. I'm just saying make life easy on yourself now & especially later. But, if you're cool with I don't have a problem accepting your decision.

Comment: I was kind of originally thinking that, but the 1x4 is only 3/4" thick which would leave a 1/4" gap behind the casing.   I agree that the gap would be a pain to pain, and I have some wiggle room on how wide it is based on the casing I'd pick.  From a visual standpoint it *might* make it look better by making the casing look like it pops out, instead of in if it goes against the wall.  Also, it would give me some wiggle room in case the door jam and wall aren't perfectly parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used 1x for anything in well over 10-years & that was from a lumber yard, not a home improvement place. I can agree with your reasoning, so make the gap bigger (a full inch or 2) & stick to your 1/2" plywood doubled-up or faced with drywall.